# Listview wrong position when you click it after search filtered using edittext in Android

Tags: android

I have Listview with some data also i have Edittext to search the data but the problem is when i search something and click it it goes wrong position, if i have **A**, **B** and **C** in my Listview and every letter has her own activity, then if i search **C** and click it, it goes the **A**'s activity instead of her own activity.

**Listview Code**

```
    // the Listview Data
    final String letters [] = {"A", "B", "C"};

    lv = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), R.layout.raadi_items, R.id.poem_name, letters);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Edittext Search**

```
      //letters search
     inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });
```

**OnClick Code**

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                if(position==0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("0","file:///android_asset/baaq/index.html");
                    intent.putExtra("1","A");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(position==1){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("0","file:///android_asset/barabaraale/index.html");
                    intent.putExtra("1","B");
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                else if(position==2){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("0","file:///android_asset/beeraad/index.html");
                    intent.putExtra("1","C");
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }

    });
```

And i'm using ArrayAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSCIuIbS-nk) video is helps me with out Custom Adapter only change the `onCLickListener` to

```
        //listview onclick
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("letters",lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                    startActivity(intent);

       }
   });

   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `position` to determine which activity to start and which data to sent to it. Select activity according to actual content of item you have clicked.

Customize `ArrayAdapter` as `MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable`:

```java
  class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<String> mItems;
    private List<String> mFilteredItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ValueFilter mValueFilter;

    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        super();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mItems = Arrays.asList(items);
        this.mFilteredItems = Arrays.asList(items);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mFilteredItems.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.raadi_items, null);
        }

        // bind data here and include click listener as well
        TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.poem_name);
        txt.setText(mFilteredItems.get(i));

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mValueFilter == null) {
            mValueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return mValueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null) {
                List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
                    if (mItems.get(i).contains(constraint)) {
                        filtered.add(mItems.get(i));
                    }
                }
                results.count = filtered.size();
                results.values = filtered;
            } else {
                results.count = 0;
                results.values = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            return results;
        }


        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            mFilteredItems = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

(**UPDATED**)
And then in `onItemCLickListener`:

```
  if (adapter.getItem(0).equals(adapter.getFilteredItems().get(position))) {
    // do with 'A'
  } else if (adapter.getItem(1).equals(adapter.getFilteredItems().get(position))) {
    // ...
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: does i need to create new Adapter class

Comment: @JimaleAbdi, yes you do: create new Adapter that extends `BaseAdapter` class and implements at least `Filterable` interface

Comment: i make new adapter class but there are more errors the first error is in this part  `super(context, R.layout.raadi_items, R.id.poem_name, items);` specially in the contex

Comment: There are no errors in the Adapter now but how i can get  `items` and `mFilteredItems` from Adapter class. Thank you for your effort

Comment: @JimaleAbdi, create couple of methods within the `MyBaseAdapter` like this:
```
public List<String> getItems() {
  return this.mItems;
}
```
and
```
public List<String> getFilteredItems() {
  return this.mFilteredItems;
}
```

To access specific item, you can use overriden `getItem(int position)` method

Comment: I implement the methods in Adapter class like this                             `public List<String> getItems() {
        return this.mItems; }
        
    public List<String> getFilteredItems() {

        return this.mFilteredItems; }`  but still there is a problem in `onCLickListener` `items` and `mFilteredItems`

Comment: What a problem, exactly?

Comment: Do you create `OnItemClickListener` inside the activity? If so, get items with `adapter.getFilteredItems()`.

Comment: I'm using fragment not activity